# ¿Como ocultar una columna de un datatable si es un usuario en especifico?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, datatables

Tengo un `datatable` con una columna `defaultContent`, donde tengo botones para editar, eliminar y dar privilegios pero quiero ocultarlo si el tipo de perfil es usuario, es decir, solo puede ver esa columna el administrador

usser.js...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//...
var table = $('#dt_usser').DataTable({
    "ajax": "php/usser_cargar.php",
    "columns":[
        { "data": "num_emp", "visible": false},
        { "data": "nom"},
        { "data": "nom_usu"},                   
        { "data": "tipo"},
        { "data": "status", "sClass": "dt-body-center"},
        {"defaultContent": '<div class="text-center"> <button title="Editar perfil." type="button" class="editar btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button  title="Eliminar usuario" type="button" class="eliminar btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <button title="." type="button" class="privilegios btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> </div>', "width": "15%" }
    ],"language": datables_espanol
    //...
}
```

¿Como ocultar la columna `defaultContent` con manejo de `session`?

Quise realizar una función dentro del mismo js pero me deja de mostrar todos los datos de la tabla.

```
function direc(){
   if (<?$_SESSION['usrSis_tipo'];?> === 'U'){
      table.columns([5]).visible(false);
   }

};
```

En `usser.php` esta la estructura de la tabla que se llena con el código colocado en `usser.js`, y `usser_cargar.php` se realiza la consulta a la base de datos y se mandan los datos en `JSON`

Comment: Gracias por la edición Marcos y coloque las observaciones que me hiciste pero con el mismo resultado (no aparecen los datos de la tabla)

Comment: si, modifico la redacción de la pregunta para aclararlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ocupo un js llamado priv.js coloco parte del código

```js
function cargarPrivilegios($e){
    $.ajax({
     url:'php/priv.php',
     type:"POST",   
  data:{num_emp:$e},
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(data){
            var $icono;
            if (data.exito){
                           
                if (data.ges_add){ }else{$(".btnU").remove(); }
                if (data.ges_mod){ }else{$(".editarU").remove(); }
                if (data.ges_elim){ }else{$(".eliminarU").remove(); }
    if (data.ges_priv){ }else{$(".privilegiosU").remove(); }
```

como ven en la url se ocupa un archivo php para realizar la consulta a la base de datos... también coloco parte del código del archivo priv.php

```html
$sql = "SELECT mant_acceso, mant_add, mant_mod, mant_elim, ges_acceso, ges_add, ges_mod, ges_elim, ges_priv FROM usser WHERE num_usr = '".$cbx_emplP."'";
 if (!$resultado =$conexion->query($sql)) {
  $jsondata['exito'] = false;
  $jsondata['mensaje'] = "La ejecución de la consulta falló.";
  $jsondata['tipo_mensaje'] = 'danger';
 }else{
    if($resultado->num_rows>0){
            
                       $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);         
     
                        $jsondata['exito'] = true;
              if ($data['mant_add']==1){
                            $jsondata['mant_add'] = true;    
                        }else{
                            $jsondata['mant_add'] = false; 
                        }
              
                        //-----------------------------------------
                        
                        if ($data['mant_mod']==1){
                            $jsondata['mant_mod'] = true;    
                        }else{
                            $jsondata['mant_mod'] = false; 
                        }
...
```

nos regresamos al archivo priv.js en la función observamos  que en cada if es donde verifico si se tiene el privilegio, no pasa nada se muestra, pero sino se tiene el privilegio, remuevo el botón con su respectiva clase

Answer (score 0):

valida el perfil de usuario desde la base de datos, si por ejemplo no se los quieres mostrar a los cajeros no lo agregues en el if que te puse abajo

```
if ( isset(user['admin']) or isset(user['superusuario'])){
<td>'.$columna['campo'].'</td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple (*pero no muy elegante*) podría ser:

- En el archivo `usser.php` guardas el valor de la variable de `PHP` `$_SESSION['usrSis_tipo']` en una variable global de `JS` (ejemplo `window.usrTipo`)

  ```
  <!-- ... Código ... -->
  <script>window.usrTipo = "<?= $_SESSION['usrSis_tipo'] ?>"</script>
  <script src="{PATH}/usser.js"></script>
  <!-- ... Código ... -->
  ```
- En el archivo `usser.js`, deberías consumir dicha variable para validar el nivel

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //...
    var table = $('#dt_usser').DataTable({
      "ajax": "php/usser_cargar.php",
      "columns":[
        //...
        {
          "visible": window.usrTipo !== 'U', // Si no usuario
          "defaultContent": '<div class="text-center"> <button title="Editar...',
          "width": "15%"
        }
      ],
      "language": datables_espanol
      //...
  ```

Comment: "+1" gracias Marcos por tu aporte, un saludo!!! ahorita estoy checando algo que se me ocurrió, término, lo checo haber que pasa :)

Comment: @RoiiSantos, si encontraste otra solución, siempre puedes crear una respuesta. Después de 2 días la puedes marcar como la mas acertada. Por otro lado, si alguna de las respuestas recibidas te sirvió para solucionar tu problema, considera votarla y/o marcarla como la mas acertada.

Comment: disculpa la tardanza ya quedo comento el código